# Openlayers freehand intersection

Tags: openlayers

I was trying to get intersection points of 2 freehand drawings in openlayers. Freehand coordinates do not have point by point coordinates and it has only changing coordinates of a freehand drawing. Because of that i cannot get the specific intersection coordinates of 2 free hand drawings.Is there a way to get coordinates of intersection points of two freehand drawings in Openlayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to transform your freehand drawing to geojson.

From there you should be able to perform intersection using [turfjs](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf) / [turf-intersect](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-intersect)